# Having text appear on hover CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles, hover

```
  <div class="acontainer">
<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/ashley">
    <img  class="thumb" src="{{ 'f1.jpeg' | asset_url }}"><br>
    <p id="wrapper" class="text">text</p>

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/panthera">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f2.jpeg' | asset_url }}"><br>

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/evie">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f3.jpeg' | asset_url }}">

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/tempest">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f4.jpeg' | asset_url }}">

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/triumvirate">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f5.jpg' | asset_url }}">

</a>
```

```
<style type="text/css">

.acontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 158px;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:145px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
}


.acontainer a {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumb{
    width:140px;
    margin: auto;
}


a:hover .thumb {
  top: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}

</style>
```

I've tried styling visibility in CSS to get the text to appear on the hover, but what happens is that the text is always there, and is affected by the opacity.

I want "text" appear when I hover over the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes...

1º - Your CSS is wrong...

```
#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

If you wanna reference the 'p' tag that contains the text you just need to use .text { visibility:visible } as .text isn't child of #wrapper... another solution is to use #wrapper:hover.text....

2º - You are setting and wrapper on the

itself, you need to set the wrapper on the main link...

Here we go with your code corrected:

```
<div class="acontainer">
<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/ashley" id="wrapper">
    <img  class="thumb" src="{{ 'f1.jpeg' | asset_url }}"><br>
    <p class="text">123123</p>
</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/panthera">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f2.jpeg' | asset_url }}"><br>

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/evie">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f3.jpeg' | asset_url }}">

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/tempest">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f4.jpeg' | asset_url }}">

</a>

<a href="http://www.teamanco.com/products/triumvirate">
    <img class="thumb" src="{{ 'f5.jpg' | asset_url }}">

</a>

<style type="text/css">

.acontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 158px;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:145px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
}

.acontainer a {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumb{
    width:140px;
    margin: auto;
}


a:hover .thumb {
  top: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}

</style>
```

I suggest you study "Child/Parent relationships on CSS"...
Btw, Good luck :D

Comment: set the opacity on #wrapper .text, so when the hover effects goes on the text is already at the right opacity avoiding lag issues ;)